# How to fix Div element "jump" on drag?

Tags: javascript, html, css

The dragging works but the bug is that when I drag the element somehow "**jumps**" and does **not** **flow** with the mouse. See it in the code. Don't worry about removing event listeners, I will add them as soon as this works.
I have an issue on a draggable "div" element. I've searched many answers before I posted this question but nothing seems to be the solution(or maybe I am not understanding the problem really well).
Thank you!

```js
const hotspot = document.getElementsByClassName("hotspot")[0];
const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
let containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
let hsRect = hotspot.getBoundingClientRect();

let relMouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let windowMouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let isUserIntercating = false;

const handlePointerUp = (e) => {
  isUserIntercating = false;
};

const handlePointerDown = (e) => {
  isUserIntercating = true;
  hsRect = hotspot.getBoundingClientRect();
  relMouse = { x: e.pageX - hsRect.x, y: e.pageY - hsRect.y };

  window.addEventListener("pointerup", handlePointerUp, false);
};

const handlePointerMove = (e) => {
  hsRect = hotspot.getBoundingClientRect();
  containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  windowMouse = { x: e.clientX - relMouse.x, y: e.clientY - relMouse.y };
};
const update = (t) => {
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
  if (isUserIntercating) {
    hotspot.style.transform = `translate(${
      windowMouse.x - containerRect.x
    }px,0px)`;
  }
};
update();
hotspot.addEventListener("pointerdown", handlePointerDown, false);
window.addEventListener("pointermove", handlePointerMove, false);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.hotspot {
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: aqua;
  /* transform: translate(100px, 100px); */
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hotspot"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try like this:

```js
const hotspot = document.getElementsByClassName("hotspot")[0];
const container = document.getElementsByClassName("container")[0];
let containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
let hsRect = hotspot.getBoundingClientRect();

let relMouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let windowMouse = { x: 0, y: 0 };
let isUserIntercating = false;

const handlePointerUp = (e) => {
  isUserIntercating = false;
};

const handlePointerDown = (e) => {
  isUserIntercating = true;
  hsRect = hotspot.getBoundingClientRect();
  relMouse = { x: e.pageX - hsRect.x, y: e.pageY - hsRect.y };

  window.addEventListener("pointerup", handlePointerUp, false);
};

const handlePointerMove = (e) => {
  hsRect = hotspot.getBoundingClientRect();
  containerRect = container.getBoundingClientRect();
  windowMouse = { x: e.clientX - relMouse.x, y: e.clientY - relMouse.y };
  requestAnimationFrame(update);
};
const update = (t) => {
  if (isUserIntercating) {
    hotspot.style.transform = `translate(${
      windowMouse.x - containerRect.x
    }px,0px)`;
  }
};
hotspot.addEventListener("pointerdown", handlePointerDown, false);
window.addEventListener("pointermove", handlePointerMove, false);
```

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
}
.container {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 50px;
  max-width: 600px;
  min-height: 600px;
  background-color: blanchedalmond;
}

.hotspot {
  /* position: absolute; */
  background-color: aqua;
  /* transform: translate(100px, 100px); */
  min-height: 100px;
  max-width: 100px;
  z-index: 200;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    
    <title>Parcel Sandbox</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <div class="hotspot"></div>
    </div>
    <script src="src/index.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The issue seemed to be that the `update` function kept calling itself all the time, which is not really ideal. The `update` should only be called in the `handlePointerMove` function (only change the hotspot position when the mouse moves).

Comment: Thank you! Really nice explanation about the requestAnimationFrame(), I tried to debug it alot but it's kinda hard.